Stripe error - $config must be a string or an array
I'm using Laravel with Vue.js for my application, and I’m encountering an issue when trying to create a Stripe Checkout session. Specifically, when a user attempts to place an order, I get the following error:
{     "status": "error",     "message": "There was an error creating the checkout session: $config must be a string or an array" }

this is my request code:
const fullName = ref(null);
const gender = ref(null);
const nationalCardID = ref(null);
const purchase = async () => {
    const button = document.getElementById('purchase-btn');
    button.innerHTML = '<span class="loading loading-spinner loading-md"></span>';
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    try {
        await axios.post('/order-checkout', {
            offerId: selectedOffer.value.id,
            quantity: checked.value ? 2 : 1,
            fullName: fullName.value,
            gender: gender.value,
            nationalCardID: nationalCardID.value,
        }).then((res) => {
            goToStripeCheckout(res.data.checkout_url)
        }).catch(async (err) => {
            toast.error(err.response.data.message);
            console.error('Error placing order:', err);
            showModal.value = false
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
            showModal.value = true;
        });
    } catch (error) {
        toast.error(error);
        console.error('Unexpected error:', error);
    }
    button.innerHTML = 'Purchase'
};

and this is my backend function:
public function orderCheckout(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'offerId' => 'required|integer|exists:offers,id',
            'quantity' => 'required|integer',
            'fullName' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'gender' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'nationalCardID' => 'required|string|max:500'
        ]);
    
        $offer = Offer::find($validatedData['offerId']);
    
        if (!$offer) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'error',
                'message' => 'Offer not found.'
            ], 404);
        }
    
        try {
            $stripe = new StripeClient(env('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'));
    
            $checkout_session = $stripe->checkout->sessions->create([
                'line_items' => [[
                    'price_data' => [
                        'currency' => 'usd',
                        'product_data' => [
                            'name' => $offer->name,
                        ],
                        'unit_amount' => $offer->total_with_tax * 100,
                    ],
                    'quantity' => $validatedData['quantity'],
                ]],
                'mode' => 'payment',
                'success_url' => config('app.frontend_url') . '/checkout/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
                'cancel_url' => config('app.frontend_url') . '/checkout/cancel',
            ]);
    
            $order_id = uniqid() . mt_rand(100000, 999999);
    
            $order = new Order();
            $order->order_id = $order_id;
            $order->status = 'unpaid';
            $order->total_price = $offer->total_with_tax;
            $order->session_id = $checkout_session->id;
            $order->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $order->offer_id = $validatedData['offerId'];
            $order->full_name = $validatedData['fullName'];
            $order->gender = $validatedData['gender'];
            $order->national_card_id = $validatedData['nationalCardID'];
            $order->save();
    
            $countOrdersCacheKey = 'count_orders';
            if (Cache::get($countOrdersCacheKey)) {
                Cache::forget($countOrdersCacheKey);
            }
            
            $admins = User::where('is_admin', 1)->pluck('id');
            DB::transaction(function () use ($admins) {
                $notifications = [];
                foreach ($admins as $adminId) {
                    $notifications[] = [
                        'user_id' => $adminId,
                        'created_at' => now(),
                        'updated_at' => now(),
                    ];
                }
                OrderNotification::insert($notifications);
    
                event(new OrderNotifications('New Order! Check it out'));
    
                foreach ($admins as $adminId) {
                    Cache::forget("order_notifications_{$adminId}");
                }
            });
    
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'success',
                'message' => 'Checkout session created successfully.',
                'checkout_url' => $checkout_session->url,
                'order_id' => $order_id,
                'order' => $order
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'error',
                'message' => 'There was an error creating the checkout session: ' . $e->getMessage()
            ], 500);
        }
    }

I have set the stripe secret key successfully in my .env file, and I’m using the latest version of the Stripe PHP SDK.

There is no $config variable in your code, either sharing the full error stack would help, of course after doing some debugging and share it's results too

It's likely that your config variable here has an unexpected value. You could try to debug and make sure you have proper value of config('app.frontend_url') and config('app.frontend_url') (Or maybe you have an error in syntax?)
'success_url' => config('app.frontend_url') . '/checkout/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
'cancel_url' => config('app.frontend_url') . '/checkout/cancel',
        ]);

